# Refactoring: Converting future.get() to CompletionStage.whenComplete()?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I currently have some code in Java which looks something like this, but I want to refactor this.

```java
List<Object> combinedStatus = new ArrayList();
for (List<Long> batch: batches){
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = ask(batch);
    futureHolder.add(future);
}

try {
   for (CompletableFuture<Object> future: futureHolder) { 
      response = future.get();
      combinedStatus.add(response.result());
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // log exception 
   }

//return combinedStatus;
```

I see one major issue is that future.get() is blocking the thread. I want to refactor this to make it non blocking. Here is my refactored version - can someone give me some advice on if this is correct / makes sense / or how I can make this better?

```java
for (List<Long> batch: batches) {
   CompletionStage<Object> stage = ask(batch);
    stage.whenComplete(
        (resp, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
             // log exception 
           } else { 
               combinedStatus.add(response.result());
           }
     });
}

//return combinedStatus;
```

Any suggestions / what is the idiomatic approach to refactoring this?

Comment: Your return value should itself be a `CompletableFuture`.  If that's not the case, your code is wrong.

Comment: Which return value?

Comment: When you write `return combinedStatus`, you're returning a value of type `List`.  You're not returning a CompletableFuture.  That's enough to verify that your code is wrong.

Comment: return in the second or the first snippet? this return is outside the scope of the completionStage / completableFuture operations. It's just a datastructure in which i'm collecting the results of what i get from these futures / stages. It's part of a function. I have commented it as it's confusing without the entire function signature.

Comment: The second snippet.  If you don't return a CompletableFuture, then it _must_ block (or not actually work).  Right now, what actually happens is you return an empty list because you don't wait for the futures to complete, so it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want it to be "outside the scope of the completionStage / completableFuture operations," then there is no correct solution that doesn't block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not avoid blocking for a method that is supposed to return the final result, i.e. the `List<Object>`. The only way to make this method non-blocking, is by returning a future for the final result.

Then, the most straight-forward way to deal with a list of futures, is to keep the loop, but perform it as a chained operation, when all futures are known to be completed, so querying the result won’t block.

```java
for(List<Long> batch: batches) {
    futureHolder.add(ask(batch));
}

return CompletableFuture.allOf(futureHolder.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
    .thenApply(justVoid -> {
        List<Object> combinedStatus = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CompletableFuture<Object> future: futureHolder) {
            combinedStatus.add(future.join().result());
        }
        return combinedStatus;
    });
```

The returned future will be completed exceptionally if any of the operation failed with an exception, so you don’t need to deal with exceptions within this code. The caller of you method can decide how to deal with exceptional results.